# I'm making a text game, some options are just ignored but I get no errors

Tags: java

So I started working on this Java text game and a few options will not do anything, but just end the program. The ones I noticed so far are the press 2 to leave the gun be, and heading right in the corridor. The code is huge so sorry, im new to Java to it will be messy as hell but I really need help. I've been working on this for hours and just noticed those parts didn't work and I'm stumped :/ Anyways here it the code (Sorry for formatting errors I am bad at formatting on here)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Spookster

{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int actionOne, actionTwo, actionThree, actionFour, actionFive, actionSix, actionSeven, actionEight, actionNine;

    System.out.println("You wake up in a metallic room. There is a knife next to you, and there is a door ahead of you.");
    System.out.print("Enter 1 to go to the door, enter 2 to pick up the knife: ");
    actionOne = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (actionOne == 1) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("You walk to the door. There is a small window that you could look through.");
        System.out.println("You could also just open the door right there.");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to look through the window, enter 2 to go through the door: ");
        actionTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (actionTwo == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
            System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
        } else if (actionTwo == 2) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
            System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself: ");
        }

    } else if (actionOne == 2) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("You pick up the knife and hear something behind you.");
        System.out.println("You blindly throw your hand backwards and realise you killed a tall creature.");
        System.out.println("There is an advanced gun in his hand");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to pick up the gun, enter 2 to leave it be: ");
        actionThree = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (actionThree == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You grab the gun and the creature moves, you quickly aim and fire");
            System.out.println("The creature drops dead. You take a look around and notice a corridor.");
            System.out.println("You head down the corridor and it splits.");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to head left, enter 2 to head right: ");
            actionFour = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (actionFour == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You head left. There is a control panel that controls an escape pod");
                System.out.println("There are two buttons, a blue button and a yellow button.");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to press the blue button, enter 2 to press the yellow button: ");
                actionFive = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actionFive == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You press the blue button. The ship begins to shake.");
                    System.out.println("You take your last breath as the ship explodes");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                } else if (actionFive == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You press the yellow button. The escape pod door opens.");
                    System.out.println("You walk inside and hear something behind you.");
                    System.out.println("There are two switches in an alien language. One must control the door.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to activate the left switch, enter 2 to activate the right switch.");
                    actionSeven = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionSeven == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You activate the left switch and the hatch closes.");
                        System.out.println("There is only one other switch, you activate it.");
                        System.out.println("The escape pod launches from the ship. On the descent down you see the alien ship come towards earth.");
                        System.out.println("Seconds later the ship is blown to bits. Once you land you are greeted by a govenment agency");
                        System.out.println("They thank you for baiting the ship in, and give you a medal for your accomplishments.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - BAD ENDING");
                    } else if (actionSeven == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You activate the right switch and the escape pod launches into space.");
                        System.out.println("You see the alien bodies fly out of the ship before your eyes pop");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    }
            } else if (actionFour == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You head right. There is an armory filled with alien weapons.");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to get an alien rifle, enter 2 to leave the weapons and continue down the hall: ");
                actionSix = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actionSix == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You pick up an alien rifle. It sends off an alarm.");
                    System.out.println("Multiple aliens are rushing down the halls. You pick off a few.");
                    System.out.println("Suddenly you feel pain in your stomache and you drop to the floor.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                } else if (actionSix == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You decide it's not worth the risk.");
                    System.out.println("You keep heading down the corridor and find some type of needle filled with liquid.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to inject the liquid into you, enter 2 to leave it: ");
                    actionEight = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionEight == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You inject the liquid and see your arms and body slowly vanish.");
                        System.out.println("It seems you injected yourself with a cloaking syrum.");
                        System.out.println("Seconds later an alien comes in. It growls then moves off looking for you.");
                        System.out.println("Heading down the corridor you see another alien, this one looks different.");
                        System.out.println("It wears a cloak and crown, and looks to be of high status.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to attempt to communicate, enter 2 to remain silent: ");
                        actionNine = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionNine == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You speak in english 'Why am I here?!'");
                            System.out.println("To your surprise the alien responds in English");
                            System.out.println("He says 'We were testing humans, you seem like a smart one");
                            System.out.println("He says 'I would like to take you back to our home system.'");
                            System.out.println("He says 'After seeing what you can do, I believe you could help us in our galactic republic'");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("1 Year Later");
                            System.out.println("You are now part of a galactic republic lightyears away. You have forgotten your old life.");
                            System.out.println("Something has made you forget it, but that doesn't matter now. You are a part of their military.");
                            System.out.println("You don't question their motives, because you have no reason to.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - GOOD ENDING");
                        } else if (actionNine == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You suddenly feel weak. A crunching feeling is in your body.");
                            System.out.println("It seems the alien knew you were there. He is much more powerful than the rest.");
                            System.out.println("Your insides begin to hurt until blood bursts from your stomach, you fall to the ground.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actionEight == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You leave the needle there.");
                        System.out.println("Suddenly a blade pierces through you. An alien has sneaked up on you.");
                        System.out.println("As your vision fades to black, you feel absolute terror.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        }
        }

        } else if (actionThree == 2) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you, you stand in fear.");
            System.out.println("Suddenly you hear a loud noise and everything is black.");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
        }
    }
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your if statement braces are probably screwed up. Indent your code properly and it'll be easier to match closing and opening braces and search for extras/missing ones.

Comment: Try to beautify your code here: http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer

Comment: I just tried it DDan and it made it look nice, but still wont work for those 2 parts :C I'm so lost D:

Comment: So many System.print statements in here. Too messy. I say create a json/xml file to store the gameplay flow. Keep one variable to read the keypress and one to store in which level/action/step you are in. Do u get what I am suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will be extremely hard to maintain and debug and change.
I suggest to refactor it and give it a bit of structure. I.e.:

```
    if (actionOne == 1) {
        System.out.println(getActionMessage1());
        actionTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (actionTwo == 1) {
            System.out.println(getActionMessage1_1());
        } else if (actionTwo == 2) {
            System.out.println(getActionMessage1_2());
        }
    } else ...

public String getActionMessage1() {
    return "The long string now is not making your logic with decisions hard to understand" +
           "and it's easy to change the messages without affectiong your code logic"
}
```

Of course a lot of things can be considered here for a more clever design, but this fist step would make it much easier.

For the indentation issues you can use: [codebeautify.org/javaviewer](http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer)

Once you fix this issue, you will be able to fix your code in no time.

**UPDATE**

Your action three and action four were not aligning, also eighth and nine. Try with this code. I was lazy to do the refactoring I suggested... But I highly recommend it, if you ever plan on changing your code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Spookster

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        int actionOne, actionTwo, actionThree, actionFour, actionFive, actionSix, actionSeven, actionEight, actionNine;

        System.out.println("You wake up in a metallic room. There is a knife next to you, and there is a door ahead of you.");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to go to the door, enter 2 to pick up the knife: ");
        actionOne = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (actionOne == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You walk to the door. There is a small window that you could look through.");
            System.out.println("You could also just open the door right there.");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to look through the window, enter 2 to go through the door: ");
            actionTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (actionTwo == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
                System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            } else if (actionTwo == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
                System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself: ");
            }

        } else if (actionOne == 2) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You pick up the knife and hear something behind you.");
            System.out.println("You blindly throw your hand backwards and realise you killed a tall creature.");
            System.out.println("There is an advanced gun in his hand");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to pick up the gun, enter 2 to leave it be: ");
            actionThree = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (actionThree == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You grab the gun and the creature moves, you quickly aim and fire");
                System.out.println("The creature drops dead. You take a look around and notice a corridor.");
                System.out.println("You head down the corridor and it splits.");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to head left, enter 2 to head right: ");
                actionFour = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actionFour == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You head left. There is a control panel that controls an escape pod");
                    System.out.println("There are two buttons, a blue button and a yellow button.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to press the blue button, enter 2 to press the yellow button: ");
                    actionFive = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionFive == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You press the blue button. The ship begins to shake.");
                        System.out.println("You take your last breath as the ship explodes");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actionFive == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You press the yellow button. The escape pod door opens.");
                        System.out.println("You walk inside and hear something behind you.");
                        System.out.println("There are two switches in an alien language. One must control the door.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to activate the left switch, enter 2 to activate the right switch.");
                        actionSeven = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionSeven == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You activate the left switch and the hatch closes.");
                            System.out.println("There is only one other switch, you activate it.");
                            System.out.println("The escape pod launches from the ship. On the descent down you see the alien ship come towards earth.");
                            System.out.println("Seconds later the ship is blown to bits. Once you land you are greeted by a govenment agency");
                            System.out.println("They thank you for baiting the ship in, and give you a medal for your accomplishments.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - BAD ENDING");
                        } else if (actionSeven == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You activate the right switch and the escape pod launches into space.");
                            System.out.println("You see the alien bodies fly out of the ship before your eyes pop");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (actionFour == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You head right. There is an armory filled with alien weapons.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to get an alien rifle, enter 2 to leave the weapons and continue down the hall: ");
                    actionSix = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionSix == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You pick up an alien rifle. It sends off an alarm.");
                        System.out.println("Multiple aliens are rushing down the halls. You pick off a few.");
                        System.out.println("Suddenly you feel pain in your stomache and you drop to the floor.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actionSix == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You decide it's not worth the risk.");
                        System.out.println("You keep heading down the corridor and find some type of needle filled with liquid.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to inject the liquid into you, enter 2 to leave it: ");
                        actionEight = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionEight == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You inject the liquid and see your arms and body slowly vanish.");
                            System.out.println("It seems you injected yourself with a cloaking syrum.");
                            System.out.println("Seconds later an alien comes in. It growls then moves off looking for you.");
                            System.out.println("Heading down the corridor you see another alien, this one looks different.");
                            System.out.println("It wears a cloak and crown, and looks to be of high status.");
                            System.out.print("Enter 1 to attempt to communicate, enter 2 to remain silent: ");
                            actionNine = keyboard.nextInt();
                            if (actionNine == 1) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("You speak in english 'Why am I here?!'");
                                System.out.println("To your surprise the alien responds in English");
                                System.out.println("He says 'We were testing humans, you seem like a smart one");
                                System.out.println("He says 'I would like to take you back to our home system.'");
                                System.out.println("He says 'After seeing what you can do, I believe you could help us in our galactic republic'");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("1 Year Later");
                                System.out.println("You are now part of a galactic republic lightyears away. You have forgotten your old life.");
                                System.out.println("Something has made you forget it, but that doesn't matter now. You are a part of their military.");
                                System.out.println("You don't question their motives, because you have no reason to.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - GOOD ENDING");
                            } else if (actionNine == 2) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("You suddenly feel weak. A crunching feeling is in your body.");
                                System.out.println("It seems the alien knew you were there. He is much more powerful than the rest.");
                                System.out.println("Your insides begin to hurt until blood bursts from your stomach, you fall to the ground.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                            }
                        } else if (actionEight == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You leave the needle there.");
                            System.out.println("Suddenly a blade pierces through you. An alien has sneaked up on you.");
                            System.out.println("As your vision fades to black, you feel absolute terror.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (actionThree == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you, you stand in fear.");
                System.out.println("Suddenly you hear a loud noise and everything is black.");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd add two principles here: method should not be longer than 15 lines and only one indentation allowed within the method. So I would refactor your refactored code even further putting `actionTwo == keyboard.nextInt();`and the following lines into a separate method.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned this would be a first step to a more structured code, also could consider to have `getActionMessage` accepting parameters and returning the messages from a prefilled container, so it would only need one method to retrieve the messages.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding `getActionMessage` methods improves the readability. Fixing the indentation definitely would.

Comment: It definitely would because it separates the decision making logic from the string constants.

Comment: @ZachThePwn Give it a try

Comment: Hey thank you man, that fixed all the problems, I'm still trying to figure out how to do most of the stuff in java because I'm just in an intro to Computer Science class in my High School xD. @DDan

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hard coding everything seperate out code and data like in the following way. I have put the level data in the json file levels.json.

Library for parsing json is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip). Extract out the jar file and put it into the build path of your java project.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line;
        try{
            //First read in the whole file into a string
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("src/levels.json"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Reading line by line
                //Append it to String builder
                out.append(line);  
            }

            //File has been read
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Press 1 or 2:");
            int action;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(out.toString());
            //Loop n number of times
            //n is the depth of your game
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                action = keyboard.nextInt();

                //Choose the tag depending on keypress
                String name = new String();
                switch(action){
                case 1:
                    name = new String("k1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = new String("k2");
                    break;
                }           
                //Go deeper into the game
                json = json.getJSONObject(name);
                //Print the message
                System.out.println(json.getString("message"));
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException fe){
            fe.printStackTrace();           
        }catch(JSONException ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "k1":{
        "message": "Enter 1 to look through the window, enter 2 to go through the door.",
        "k1": {
                "message":"YOU ARE DEAD"
            },
        "k2": {
                "message":"defend yourself."
            }
    },
    "k2":{
        "message" : "Enter 1 to pick up the gun, enter 2 to leave it be",
        "k1": {
                "message":"You grab the gun and the creature moves."
            },

        "k2":{
                "message":"The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you."
            }
    }
}
```